# Class Yii is not found when posting a variable with ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, yii

I want to get a variable from ajax to php. I'm using the Yii framework.
So my problem is, when I want to transfer a variable from ajax to a php script I get this error:

> Fatal error: Class 'Yii' not found in
>   /var/www/vhosts/adappter.de/comamos/protected/views/store/search_area.php
>   on line 44  store.js:1308:13

This is how my Ajax Call looks like

```
var selectedCuisine = [];
$( document ).on( "click", "#cuisines", function() 
{
    if ( $(this).is(':checked') ) 
    {
        selectedCuisine.push($(this).val());
    }
        // document.getElementById('cuisine-list').style.visibility='hidden';
   $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "../protected/views/store/search_area.php",
        data: {cuisine : selectedCuisine}, 

        success: function(response){
            console.log(response);
        }
    });

});
```

and this is my php script to line 44

```
<?php 
if (!isset($_SESSION)) { session_start(); }

$_SESSION['search_type']='';
if (isset($_GET['s'])){
  $_SESSION['kr_search_address']=$_GET['s'];
  $_SESSION['search_type']='kr_search_address';
}

unset($_SESSION['kr_item']);
unset($_SESSION['kr_merchant_id']);

$marker=Yii::app()->functions->getOptionAdmin('map_marker');
if (!empty($marker)){
   echo CHtml::hiddenField('map_marker',$marker);
}
?>
```

The jQuery call is only when I click on a checkbox. So the value of the selected box gets pushed in an array. I want to return the array to the php script.
When I'm loading the site, I don't get such an error. So I don't know why this error occurs.

Comment: Looks like the `yii` add on isn't loaded.

Comment: But it's always loaded also when the site is refreshed. So if ajax is calling the script again, the framework should load also, or did i understood it wrong?

Comment: It's on your webpage, but not on the server page requested by your ajax call. Those two files aren't connected.

Comment: All request must processing from index file. You have problem because core of framework connected in index.php file. You need to use [controller](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/basics.controller), not view file. And call ajax like this: `$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/namecontroller/nameaction", ...`

Comment: @DanilaGanchar when I call the controller how can I get the variable respectively how to "refresh" the site, that I get the variable to make a call from this script

Comment: @TdoubleG and you can use `Yii::app()->session;` for work with sessions. Like this: `Yii::app()->session->add('my', 'myVar'); echo Yii::app()->session->get('my'); Yii::app()->session->offsetExists('my'); // etc. `

Answer (score 2):

You need to use controller with action. Not only view file. You try to call view file from web. But it is wrong, because all code in protected directory. All requests must processing from index file. In index file connected framework. Here a small example. Controller:

```
class SiteController extends Controller
    public function actionTest()
    {
        //... example
        echo CHtml::button('test');
    }
```

js:

```
var selectedCuisine = [];
$( document ).on( "click", "#cuisines", function() 
{
    if ( $(this).is(':checked') ) 
    {
        selectedCuisine.push($(this).val());
    }
        // document.getElementById('cuisine-list').style.visibility='hidden';
   $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/site/test", // url for your action
        data: {cuisine : selectedCuisine}, 

        success: function(response){
            console.log(response);
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: Thank for your response, but I don't really get it :/.
I have 2 questions. 
There is already an PHP Script called SiteController. Shell I use it and post the variable from the JS there?
Second question is, should the ajax URL parameter point to the SiteController script with the defined function?

Comment: @TdoubleG ok. Just create test action and check that it's works. For example, here code of action: `echo json_encode(array($_GET, $_POST));`. And call like this:  `$.ajax({ type: "GET", url: "/site/test",  data: {cuisine : 'testValue'}, success: function(response) { console.log(response); }});`